# Submitting Electron App to Mac App Store: Error "Invalid Signature"

Tags: macos, app-store, electron, mac-app-store

I'm trying to submit an Electron based app to the Mac App Store.
To sign the app I'm using this script (according to https://github.com/atom/electron/blob/master/docs/tutorial/mac-app-store-submission-guide.md):

```
#!/bin/bash
# Name of your app.
APP="MyApp"
# The path of you app to sign.
APP_PATH="MyApp.app"
# The path to the location you want to put the signed package.
RESULT_PATH="$APP.pkg"
# The name of certificates you requested.
APP_KEY="3rd Party Mac Developer Application: MYCOMPANY (XXX)"
INSTALLER_KEY="3rd Party Mac Developer Installer: MYCOMPANY (XXX)"

FRAMEWORKS_PATH="$APP_PATH/Contents/Frameworks"

codesign --deep -fs "$APP_KEY" --entitlements child.plist "$FRAMEWORKS_PATH/Electron Framework.framework/Versions/A"
codesign --deep -fs "$APP_KEY" --entitlements child.plist "$FRAMEWORKS_PATH/$APP Helper.app/"
codesign --deep -fs "$APP_KEY" --entitlements child.plist "$FRAMEWORKS_PATH/$APP Helper EH.app/"
codesign --deep -fs "$APP_KEY" --entitlements child.plist "$FRAMEWORKS_PATH/$APP Helper NP.app/"
codesign --deep -fs "$APP_KEY" --entitlements child.plist "$FRAMEWORKS_PATH/$APP Framework.framework/Libraries/libnode.dylib"
codesign --deep -fs "$APP_KEY" --entitlements child.plist "$FRAMEWORKS_PATH/$APP Framework.framework/Electron Framework"

# Signage of terminal-notifier
codesign --deep -fs "$APP_KEY" --entitlements child.plist "$APP_PATH/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/node-notifier/vendor/terminal-notifier.app"

if [ -d "$FRAMEWORKS_PATH/Squirrel.framework/Versions/A" ]; then
    # Signing a non-MAS build.
    codesign --deep -fs "$APP_KEY" --entitlements child.plist "$FRAMEWORKS_PATH/Mantle.framework/Versions/A"
    codesign --deep -fs "$APP_KEY" --entitlements child.plist "$FRAMEWORKS_PATH/ReactiveCocoa.framework/Versions/A"
    codesign --deep -fs "$APP_KEY" --entitlements child.plist "$FRAMEWORKS_PATH/Squirrel.framework/Versions/A"
fi
codesign -fs "$APP_KEY" --entitlements parent.plist "$APP_PATH"

productbuild --component "$APP_PATH" /Applications --sign "$INSTALLER_KEY" "$RESULT_PATH"
```

with the two entitlements files:
**child.plist**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
   <dict>
      <key>com.apple.security.app-sandbox</key>
      <true/>
      <key>com.apple.security.inherit</key>
      <true/>
   </dict>
</plist>
```

and **parent.plist**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>com.apple.security.app-sandbox</key>
    <true/>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

After running the script I used the Application Loader to submit the PKG-File to the MAS. So far its working. But after the submitting process I'm receiving a mail from Apple with the following error:

> Invalid Signature - This error occurs when you have signed your app's installer incorrectly. There are two certs required for this process: the "3rd Party Mac Developer Application" cert and the "3rd Party Mac Developer Installer" cert. When signing your package, you need to ensure that you are using the Installer cert to sign your package. Ensure that you are specifying this cert when submitting your app via the Xcode Organizer or when running productbuild from the command line.

I used the "3rd Party Mac Developer Installer" cert to sign the package. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

After you generated the package by electron-packager.
You shoud edit the info.plist in the package.
Add a pair of (key,value) to info.plist. The key is "ElectronTeamId" and the value is your Team ID.
To locate your Team ID, Sign in to Apple Developer Center, and click Membership in the sidebar. Your Team ID appears in the Membership Information section under the team name.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend have a check on [`electron-osx-sign`](https://npmjs.org/package/electron-osx-sign). From the excerpts of your signing script it's slightly uncertain to tell where the process went wrong. So with this module, all you'll have to do is:

`$ electron-osx-sign path/to/my.app`

And the rest of setting up entitlements and signing different versions of the containing frameworks could be done for you.